# Apache2 HTTP POST and GET result in 500 Internal Server Error | Debian

Tags: linux, apache, http, debian

I'm facing the problem that HTTP GET and POST requests result in a 500 Error on my Server while normal urls without any request Methods works fine.

I have an Apache2 with Debian 8.7 Server. 
My apache2.conf looks like this:

```
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

As you can see POST and GET arent disabled here.
My Sites and files are all in /var/www/* directions. I dont have any .htaccess files at the moment but I dont think this is nessasary.

Comment: *"normal urls without any request Methods works fine."* What does it mean ?

Comment: if I'm calling the url "http://serverip/www/html/somefile.php" it works fine. if I'm calling the url "http://serverip/www/html/somefile.php?someProperty=test" I get the 500 Internal Server Error. Because my Apache2 refuses GET Methods somehow @n00dl3

Comment: Okay, so the problem is when you use a querystring ?

Comment: yeah. connection always get closed by my server instandly and i get a 500.

Comment: has it something to do with mod_rewrite or something ? @n00dl3

Comment: Hard to tell, you need to provide more informations. Has it ever worked ? If so what has changed ? can you provide some log ? is apache2.conf the only config file, are you dealing with vhost ? There are so many parameters to take in account.

Comment: There's a thick chance that something's wrong with the PHP script itself. Getting 500 instead of a descriptive message can mean that PHP interpreter is called via FastCGI, in this case 500 becomes just a "something wrong happened" error explaining nothing. Do you use php-fpm? Anyway, like @n00dl3 asked, please provide more details regarding your web server and PHP configuration.